# Firing GridView SelectedIndexChanged from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with the implementation of SelectedIndexChanged.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCalloutTeam" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvCalloutTeam_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvCalloutTeam_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2"
                            EmptyDataText="No person found" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ededed" />
                            <Columns>
                                .......... List of columns..............
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#cccccc" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6699cc" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderWidth="1px" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#fefefe" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I have a check box on the page and CheckedChanged Event implemented on that.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTakeOutOrder" runat="server" Text="Take out of order" OnCheckedChanged="cbTakeOutOrder_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

I'm trying to set SelectedIndex of GridView from this event.

```
protected void cbTakeOutOrder_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!cbTakeOutOrder.Checked && gvCalloutTeam.Rows.Count > 0)
            gvCalloutTeam.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

But it doesn't fire the SelectedIndexChanged event of GridView.  If I select the row on UI, it fires but if I change Index in code, it doesn't fire the event.  Is there a way to invoke the event, after changing SelectedIndex in code behind?

```
  protected void gvCalloutTeam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//////////////////my logic 
}
```

Comment: Instead of firing events call methods. You can call this method from the event-handler and from wherever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on .net 4.5, you can call `SelectRow` method on the GridView:

```
protected void cbTakeOutOrder_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!cbTakeOutOrder.Checked && gvCalloutTeam.Rows.Count > 0)
        gvCalloutTeam.SelectRow(0);
}
```

Comment: Nice to know a new feature in the latest framework!! This worked for me.  I refactored code into a separate method to execute this manually for now.  But, I can use this solution as it is elegant.  Thanks